# Evaluation of polynomial modulo in $GF(2)$

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I'm new to this forum and I have a question about about modular arithmetics. My background is in computational chemistry and I work now as a software developer. For my work I need to learn about cryptography and I'm reading the book "*Cryptography Made Simple*" by Nigel P. Smart.

In paragraph 1.2 on Finite Fields, the author gives an example of polynomial modulo in $\mathbb{F}_2(x)/f(x)\mathbb{F}_2(x)$ as such:

$$(1+x+x^2)(x+x^3)\pmod{x^4+1}={\color{red}{x^2+1}}$$

However, when I do the evaluation myself I get a different result, which is confirmed by using the `PolynomialMod` function in Mathematica. I will show the steps I took below. First of all I expand the multiplication and evaluate modulo 2:

$$x^5+x^4+2x^3+x^2+x\pmod{2}=x^5+x^4+x^2+x$$

Then:

$$x^5+x^4+x^2+x\pmod{x^4+1}$$
$$x(x^4+1)+x^4+x^2\pmod{x^4+1}$$
$$x(x^4+1)+(x^4+1)+x^2-1\pmod{x^4+1}$$

Which finally results in:

$$(x+1)(x^4+1)+x^2-1\pmod{x^4+1}={\color{blue}{x^2-1}}$$

I put in attachment a [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTmr6.png) from Mathematica to confirm it matches my result. Initially I thought it was an error in the book, but in a following section the author gives another example:

$$(x^3+1)(x^4+1)\pmod{x^7+x+1}={\color{red}{x^4+x^3+x}}$$

Again, evaluating the expression manually I obtain:

$$(x^3+1)(x^4+1)\pmod{x^7+x+1}={\color{blue}{x^4+x^3-x}}$$

Which is confirmed once more by Mathematica, see [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSZ1Y.png).

Does anyone know if there is a reason behind the difference in the results? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you and apologies for the lengthy post!

Valerio

Comment: Well, $1\equiv-1\pmod 2$ so $x^4+x^3+x\equiv x^4+x^3-x\pmod 2$ etc.

Comment: The operation you are computing is not "modulo"; it is "remainder". (although this misnomer is unfortunately common)

Comment: The book calls it modulo though. It says "we can take a polynomial $f(x)$ and polynomials modulo $f(x)$ also forms a ring". Is this incorrect?

Comment: @Vale: "Modulo" in that phrase doesn't refer to the remainder operation. It refers to a *relation*. For example, $(1+x+x^2)(x+x^3)$, $x^2 + 1$, and $x^4 + x^2$ are all polynomials that are "equivalent modulo $x^4 + 1$". That is, among the true equations we can write is  $(1+x+x^2)(x+x^3) \equiv x^4 + x^2 \pmod{x^4 + 1}$. It is true, however, that the remainder when dividing $g(x) $ by $f(x)$ is a polynomial equivalent to $g(x)$ modulo $f(x)$, which is presumably part of the reason for the confusion.

Comment: In fact, two polynomials are equivalent modulo $f(x)$ if and only if dividing each by $f(x)$ gives the same remainder. Which, together with the habit of always simplifying by substituting in the remainder, is presumably the rest of the reason for the confusion.

Comment: @Hurkyl thank you for your detailed explanation, it is all clear now. Sorry if my question sounded a bit daft, but I’ve never done modular arithmetic in detail before and got a bit lost!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference; for both of the remainder calculations, your result and the solution you compared it to are the *same polynomial*.

What you are missing is that $1$ and $-1$ are the *same number* when working over $\mathrm{GF}(2)$. A common manifestation of this is that addition and subtraction are the *same operation* when working in any ring of characteristic $2$.

In particular, the following equation is true:
$$ x^2 + 1 = x^2 - 1 $$

Comment: I think I need to read a bit more about modular arithmetics, before going any further... Any books or articles to suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is no $(-1)$ , $(2)$  in binary mode $GF(2)$ so, any time you encounter a $(-1)$ , $(2)$ put it $(1)$ , $(0)$ respectively. because $1\equiv-1\pmod 2$ and $2\equiv0\pmod 2$